# Efficacy of peer monitoring in Akka

Tags: akka, monitoring, lifecycle

I am trying to wrap my brain around Akka and after reading the 2.3.11 dev guide am still a bit confused about Actor monitoring. I essentially have two main concerns:

- The messaging that occurs when a watched actors dies or is restarted; and
- The necessity or usefulness of "*peer monitoring*" in the first place

When I `context.watch(someActorRef)`, I am confused about the messaging I receive when `someActorRef` dies or is restarted. Do I get a `Terminated` message or a `DeathPactException`?

To me, monitoring is really a form of supervision, and so it only makes sense for a supervisor/parent actor to `watch` a child actor, however I believe the API takes care of this supervision automagically under the hood via supervisor strategy. So it seems like `watch`/`unwatch` are there for non-supervisor actors to...well...supervise other actors that aren't their children. So I'm concerned about *why* I would want to use these API facilities in the first place, to monitor what is essentially another "peer actor".

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Thanks @AndreasNiedermair (+1) - I appreciate the attempt to help here but if that's how you interpret that article, I think you're way off the reservation. This question is **explicitly** about Akka, and not any actor system in general. If you are arguing that SO questions shouldn't indicate the library/framework they are referencing in their titles, then I think you'll find you are a part of a *very* small constituency on this site. Reverting my title to include the word "Akka" but hopefully in a way that appeases you.

Comment: It is not about leaving out *Akka*, its the particular style of prepending this tag to the title. This is also reflected by the question I've linked to: The *... in [tag]* is way better than *[tag]: ....*, as the SO-engine automatically prepends the tags to meta information which get indexed by search engines. I must confess that I should have appended the tag instead of completely removing it though...

Comment: If you have a dependency on a particular actor instance, and you change your own internal behavior if this dependency dies then you would watch it.  Say you had a search actor and another actor needed search.  If search is not available, that other actor will return cached search results from another actor.  So this actor watches the search actor.  When it fails it toggles its internal handling to now direct searches to the cache actor while at the same time periodically checking to see when the search actor comes back up.

Comment: Thanks @cmbaxter (+1) - how about my conccern regarding what a monitoring/watching actor will receive? Let's take your example where a `QueryActor` needs a `SearchActor` and is watching it. Now the `SearchActor` dies, so the `QueryActor` needs to start using an internal cache. How does the `QueryActor` know that the `SearchActor` died? Does he receive a `Terminated` message, or is a `DeathPactException` thrown? What is a `DeathPactException`? Thanks again!

Comment: `Terminated` is the contract with watching.  It is what you will get when an actor you are watching dies.  According to the docs, `A DeathPactException is thrown by an Actor that receives a Terminated(someActor) message that it doesn't handle itself, effectively crashing the Actor and escalating to the supervisor.`  Not sure what the real use case is there though.  Also, FWIW, upvoting a comment does nothing for someones stackoverflow reputation so it's not worth mentioning every time you do it.